# How to use MQA setReportOnDoubleSlideEnabled in an iOS App?

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-qa

In the [Starting an iOS session](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSFRDS_6.3.0/com.ibm.mqa.uau.doc/topics/t_StartingAnIOSSession.html) documentation topic the `[[MQALogger defaultSettings] setReportOnDoubleSlideEnabled:false]` method is mentioned, however the library does not have such a method.

Is there a library update the contains this method, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the feature you are trying to enable is `deprecated` (meaning that is no longer maintained and could very well fail to work), and should likely *not* be used.

It might as well be that you are indeed using an MQA version that has this feature removed.

Comment: Here you can see, that IBM changes libraries but not the documentation: [http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSFRDS_6.3.0/com.ibm.mqa.uau.doc/topics/tReportingBugsOnIOSDevices.html](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSFRDS_6.3.0/com.ibm.mqa.uau.doc/topics/tReportingBugsOnIOSDevices.html)

Answer (score 0):

This question is very similar to this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28479070/mqalogger-library-and-documentation-are-not-consistent). Please see my answer to that question for more information.

Comment: Thanks, for your feedback and answer. 
We have to check that.

Regards,
Thonmas