# MQALogger – Library and documentation are not consistent

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-qa

In the [documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSFRDS_6.3.0/com.ibm.mqa.uau.doc/topics/t_StartingAnIOSSession.html) a method `[[MQALogger defaultSettings] setReportOnDoubleSlideEnabled:false]` is mentioned. But the library does not have such a method. Is there a library update that contains this method? 
The reason for this question is, that the shake gesture is already used in our application.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in version 2.x of the iOS library, APHLogger has been deprecated and replaced with MQALogger. Deprecated methods that have not been moved to MQALogger can continue to be used from APHLogger, in the near term, but they will be removed at some point in the future. It is recommended to move to the supported interface and its methods. When using the MQALogger interface, note that settings is used instead of defaultSettings. Specific to the setReportOnDoubleSlideEnabled method, try using [MQALogger showReportScreen] to launch the reporting screen.

Answer (score 0):

The double slide feature has been deprecated, so it is more than possible to have since been removed from the production rather than revived.

See this question: [How to use MQA setReportOnDoubleSlideEnabled in an iOS App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28470159/how-to-use-mqa-setreportondoubleslideenabled-in-an-ios-app)

Comment: Why does IBM not update their documentation in this case?

And is there any alternative to the double slide feature if shake is not possible???

Comment: You asked about double slide, not about shake. Shake is available, double slide is deprecated. I asked the team to check if the documentation is valid or not.

Comment: I mentioned that shake is not an option in my initial question. So, what is the alternative?